# Explain why, if $x \in F$, then $x \in {F}^{\perp\perp}$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

As far as the definition of orthogonality ${F}^{\perp} \!$  Is ${y \in E, \forall f \in F, (f|y)=0}.$

Let be $x \in F$,

We have by definition of ${F}^{\perp} \!: \forall y \in {F}^{\perp} \!, (x|y)=0$.

And then by definition of ${{F}^{\perp\perp} \! }: x \in {{F}^{\perp\perp} \! }$. But I don't understand why.

This lead to say that $F \subset {{F}^{\perp\perp} \! }$

Comment: If $x\in F$ and $y\in F^\perp$, $(x,y)=0$: $y$ is in the orthogonal of $F$. But this shows $x$ is also in the orthogonal of $F^\perp$ (apply your definition with $(y,x)=0$)! That is precisely ${F^\perp}^\perp$.

Comment: No need for the assumption that $F \bigoplus {F}^{\perp} \! =E$ to show that $F\subseteq {F}^{\perp\perp}$.

Comment: @Did Yes, indeed, but it was to show $F={{F}^{\perp\perp}}$. 
For sure, this is not part of this specifical question. Should I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, we have
$$
F^{\perp} = \{y \in X: \forall x \in F, (x|y) = 0\}\\
F^{\perp \perp} = \{y \in X: \forall x \in F^\perp, (x|y) = 0 \}
$$
Now, if $x \in F$, then by definition of $F^\perp$: $(x|y)= (y|x) = 0$ for all $y$ in $F^\perp$.  So, if $x \in F$, then it must be that $x \in F^{\perp \perp}$.